# Searching for a Maven dependency by the types it defines

Tags: maven

Say, I saw a type named a.b.c.d in a piece of code, and Eclipse couldn't resolve it. I also found no dependencies declared on its POM. Can I search for the missing dependency by that type name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With Eclipse and m2eclipse

Assuming you have checked [**Enable Full Index**](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html) for a given repository (using a **right-click** in the **Maven Repositories** view), you can search for artifacts by type in it using [**Navigate > Open Type from Maven**](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/eclipse-sect-working-repos.html) as suggested by maximdim (+1).

#### Universal

As an alternative, you can use an online repository search engine like [JARVANA](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/) that offers a search by Class.

#### References

- m2eclipse book

  - [3.7. Working with Maven Repositories](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/eclipse-sect-working-repos.html)
  - [6.4. Browsing and Manipulating Maven Repositories](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you install m2eclipse plugin - there will be 'open type from Maven' functionality in 'Navigate' menu